# Calculate displacement from initial velocity, acceleration, and drag

Tags: physics

I am creating a video game, where the drag force of an object is proportional to its velocity. Every object has a mass of $1$ so this is equivalent to a drag acceleration.

$$ a_{d} = \ln(1 - k) \times v $$

If the constant $k$ is $0.1$ then, after one second, there is a $10\%$ reduction in an object's velocity due to this force.

I have the following formula to calculate velocity from constant acceleration.

$$v = u + at$$

However, I need this to work with variable acceleration (including the drag force which depends on velocity, and a constant acceleration $a_{c}$):

$$ a = a_{c} + a_{d} $$

What changes should I make to the formula to allow this?

From there, I'm hoping to find out how to update the following formula as well, which should calculate displacement ($s$) from starting velocity ($u$), acceleration and time:

$$ s = ut + \frac{1}{2}at^2 $$

Answer (score 3):

If we take a friction which is proportional to the velocity, we have that the equation of motion is
$$a=-\beta v$$
i.e.
$$\dot{v}=-\beta v$$
Which has the solution
$$v(t)=v_0e^{-\beta t}$$
Which means that
$$v(1)=v_0e^{-\beta}$$
$$v(2)=v_0e^{-2\beta}=v_0e^{-\beta}e^{-\beta}=v(1)e^{-\beta}$$
And so on. So if we take $e^{-\beta}=0.9$, we get that $\beta=-\log(0.9)\approx 0.105361$.

If we also add an $F$ force, which results an acceleration $g$ (for example gravity), the differential equation becomes:
$$a=g-\beta v$$
i.e.
$$\ddot{x}+\beta \dot{x}=g$$
Which has the following solution:
$$x(t)=\frac{g}{\beta}t+A+Be^{-\beta t}$$
To find the constants $A$ and $B$, we can use the initial velocity $v_0$ and initial position $x_0$, because:
$$x(0)=A+B=x_0$$
and
$$v(0)=\frac{g}{\beta}-\beta B=v_0$$
which you can solve for $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I have updated the question for clarity. I now call it drag instead of friction, which probably makes sense. The drag in acceleration form is actually $D=ln(1−k) \times v$ which I figured out in [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3770858/476357).